# Why do I keep getting duplicated data from Firebase when attempting to delete something?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why do I keep getting duplicated data whenever I attempt to delete something from my firebase?  In my onStart method I received users informations suscessfully , and I am trying to delete a specific tapped item but whenever I do so I keep getting duplicated data. Why is this?

```
 //looped through Contact node access receiver UID and searched user ref for necessary information..
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        contactsRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    usersFriendsKey = dsp.getKey();
                    Log.i("friendsKey", usersFriendsKey);

                    usersRef.child(usersFriendsKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class);
                            contactsArrayList.add(userData);
                            chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            String error = databaseError.getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Deletes item

```
//Creates popup and allows user to delete a post from recycle view...
    public void deletePostMenu(final View v, final int position) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, popup.getMenu());
        selectedUserId = contactsArrayList.get(position).getUser();

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.deleteMenu:
                        contactsRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child(selectedUserId).removeValue();
                        return true;


                        default:
                        //default intent
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
```

Comment: In Firebase if you attach a listener to one node(parent) and make changes to any of its child nodes you will get a Data-Change update on the parent node irrespective of type of change. Because of this you are receiving a data change on delete.

Comment: @ImranMohammed Sounds like an answer Imran :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Imran says, when you attach an `addValueEventListener` to a reference, it will open a socket to keep listening to changes into that reference.

When you do a delete, update or any change to that reference, the trigger will fire and you will be adding new elements at that reference from your first code snippet.

What you can do is attach a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and it will only trigger once.

So, after you delete a certain node, it will not fire the other code that is listening to that node.

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        contactsRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    usersFriendsKey = dsp.getKey();
                    Log.i("friendsKey", usersFriendsKey);

                    usersRef.child(usersFriendsKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class);
                            contactsArrayList.add(userData);
                            chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            String error = databaseError.getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```